# What does "squealed to a jerky halt" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

From a story entitled:  “Evans Tries an O-level”

> The police car squealed to a jerky halt.

What's the meaning of **squealed to a jerky halt.**

I found these meanings in a dictionary

> *squealed*: made a loud sound
>
> *jerky*: sudden, quick and not smooth
>
> *halt*: end to movement

Does the sentence mean that the police car, which had been making loud sounds, suddenly stopped?

Comment: I trust you'd be happy with 'came jerkily to a halt',  '... came to a jerky halt', and with '... came, squealing, to a jerky halt'. '... squealed to a jerky halt' is a totally acceptable (in non-formal writing) paraphrase of the latter, where the verb _squeal[ed])_ is pressed into double duty, doing the work of both the verb one would normally use (came) and the adverbial. This sort of device is not uncommon in quote structures: "You almost won that time," Aloysius smirked. // If I could find supporting evidence for this particular example of this literary device, I'd put this as an 'answer'.

Comment: Please change the title, asking about the "meaning of a sentence" tells visitors absolutely nothing about the question, except that you didn't understand.

Comment: Picture a car stopping suddenly...the tires usually make a squealing sound, right?  So with the technical explanation from Edwin and this information, you should understand now that the phrase means the car stopped suddenly but the phrase "squealed to a jerky halt" paints a picture that includes sound and an image of a suddenly-stopping car.  Hope that helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, squealing is the noise some cars make when hitting the brakes while travelling at speed. When you hit brakes like that it’s very rough on the passengers and the cars’ brake discs.

https://youtu.be/igvNTN_C2ME

Here is an example I think describes a car squealing before coming to halt and crashing in this case.

Comment: didn't get what i want!